# Selenium tests on Ruby Terminates without Execution; I am using RSpec

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I am using Eclipse IDE for running `Ruby Selenium scripts` [Ruby / RSpec / WebDriver]

When I run the test, **Run As > Ruby Script** from Eclipse, I see NO errors in the console but the test is terminated instead of running the test.

[image]

Here is the sample code I tried to automate:

> ```
>   require "json"
>   require "selenium-webdriver"
>   require "rspec"
>   include RSpec::Expectations
>
>   describe "Google" do
>
>     before(:each) do
>       @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
>       @base_url = "https://google.com"      
>       @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30      
>     end
>
>     after(:each) do
>       @driver.quit      
>     end
>
>     it "test_sdf" do
>       @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
>       @driver.find_element(:name, "q").clear
>       @driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys "Hello"      
>     end    
>
>   end
> ```

In the above script, `before(:each) do` fails to execute

Comment: You should can run it through the terminal or command line. What is the error output?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's a good idea to use Eclipse to run rspec. 
Why not try running your test in command line so you're sure that you have the gem in place.

I dont see any problem in the code.

Comment: What's the problem to use eclipse?